# Error in showing min() and max() result in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I not sure why d3.min() and d3.max() return the same result in the end. Here is the code:

```
var groupByAgeAndtime = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return d.age; })
              //.key(function(d) { return d.time_in_hospital; })
              .rollup(function(v) {
                return{
                    mean_time_in_hospital : d3.mean(v, function(d){ return d.time_in_hospital;})
              } })
              .object(datapoints);

    console.log(groupByAgeAndtime);

    var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([d3.min(Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
                          return groupByAgeAndtime[d];//minimum average time spent
                        }),d3.max(Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
                          return groupByAgeAndtime[d];//maximum average time spent
                        })]).range([50,150])

    console.log('Min: ',d3.min(Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
                          return groupByAgeAndtime[d];//manimum average time spent
                        }));

    console.log('Max: ',d3.max(Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
                          return groupByAgeAndtime[d];//maximum average time spent
                        }));
```

Here is the screenshot of the console in Mozilla Firefox:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnmfm.png)

Hhere is the link for my jsfiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/james_bond100/c8rgfb9k/)

Can anyone explain to me why it behave like that? Where did I do wrong in the code?

Comment: It seems that you are passing `Object.keys(...)` to d3.min and d3.max. Keys in your object are all the same (*mean_time_in_hospital*). So the result is the same (first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of a given object's own property names.

```
Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime) // return Array(3) [ "0-10", "10-20", "20-30" ]
```

When you accessor function returns `groupByAgeAndtime[d]` you get the value of each key:

```
{ mean_time_in_hospital: 1 }
{ mean_time_in_hospital: 2 }
{ mean_time_in_hospital: 6 }
...
```

As *@jrook* has pointed out, your function get the min/max base on the keys in that objects, that is always the same: `mean_time_in_hospital`.

Instead of the `keys` from your object you want the `values` and then to return the value of the `mean_time_in_hospital` key.

```js
var groupByAgeAndtime = {
  "0-10": {
    mean_time_in_hospital: 1
  },
  "10-20": {
    mean_time_in_hospital: 2
  },
  "20-30": {
    mean_time_in_hospital: 6
  },
};

console.log('Min: ', d3.min(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d) {
  return d.mean_time_in_hospital; //manimum average time spent
}));

console.log('Max: ', d3.max(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d) {
  return d.mean_time_in_hospital; //maximum average time spent
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```